# iTunes movie player loses focus when iPhone starts syncing

Tags: iphone, itunes, movie

Frustrated by years of iTunes for Windows quirks, I finally bought a Mac Mini as a sort of media server and moved all my iTunes content over, including wifi-syncing my iPhone and iPads. I figured that iTunes would work better on a Mac.

Nope! Now, when watching a movie full screen, iTunes pops back up into the foreground whenever a device starts syncing. And the movie viewer can't be found again -- I guess it's on a different desktop?

Is this just a bug? Is there a workaround? Seems pretty odd that iTunes can't play movies full screen if there are iOS devices in the house. Surely that's not a design choice?

Comment: did you enable in itunes pref the keep movie on top?

Comment: You called it. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it. Grumbling in the comments: Why on earth would I *want* my little sync window to interrupt me while I watch a movie?? Surely that's not what the option was intended for!

Answer (score 2):

The follwoing setting should do it.

iTunes > Preferences > Advanced:

Check "Keep movie player on top of all other windows"

[image: itunes]

Comment: Whoops! Turns out that this doesn't work after all -- the little "sync window" *still* forces the iTunes library to the foreground, even when this option is set.